# Website rendering in compatibility mode in ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, compatibility, ie-compatibility-mode

I am having problems with [passyunkpost.com](http://passyunkpost.com).  I cannot replicate the problem, but the site owner is having issues with it in IE9, where the logo and other items are not working right.  I tried using this code:  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`  But this renders a blank page.

Does anyone have any suggestions of a workaround?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">  This is the code

Comment: Did you place this code right after <head> start tag, before <title>? Wasn't there any output before this meta tag, including invisible characters before doctype?

Answer (score 0):

A little late but the `meta` tag needs to be the **first** tag inside head

YES

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
```

NO

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta other-meta-tags />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
```

I've had trouble with just using the meta tag though. If you're using PHP you can also set this header. This seems to give more consistent results:

```
header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge");
```